# cURL command to Axios request with json data

Tags: javascript, curl, axios

I've got this cURL request working perfectly on remote interface just  as it should

```
curl -XGET "https://server.host:8080/peregrine" -d '{"exchanges":["kucoin", "kraken"],"volume":10}' -k
```

I'm trying to build a little frontend app with Vue.js and need the above converted to an Axios get request.
I've been trying the following so far:

```
axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://server.host/peregrine',
      data: {"exchanges":["kucoin", "kraken"],"volume":10}
    });
```

putting `params` instead of `data` makes it a URL and remote server says that it received no data.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a `POST` request with the data?

Comment: Not sure if you can send body (data) with get requests, with Axios. Encountered similar problem after using Postman GET requests and converted it to Axios.

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/787 for more info

Answer (score 5):

Likely the problem could be that using GET you cannot pass data like you are doing. You have to pass them as query parameter.
Try to change your call with:

```
axios.get('https://server.host/peregrine', {
    params: {"exchanges":["kucoin", "kraken"],"volume":10}
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that in the first place, the server wouldn't accept that, only json data. Now that we've changed the serverside, your answer totally works.

Answer (score 3):

GET requests should not have request bodies.

CURL will allow you to make a GET request with one, but XMLHttpRequest and fetch (the HTTP APIs in browsers which axios wraps) will not.

Make a POST request instead. You might need to change the server-side code to support this.

Comment: The question clearly shows the wrong HTTP Method being used; GET with a body should be a POST. Shoving POST data into the querystring isn't always appropriate. Even though the OP didn't use this approach, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your replies!

Indeed there's no way to send data body with axios.get()
We ended up tuning the server side to accept normal generic GET requests. Thanks again to everyone who answered!

Comment: -1  I upvoted your question because it showed effort and could be useful, but downvoted this because answers are not the place to comment on another answer that worked.  If a comment isn't sufficient, you could edit the original question and add this to the end.